# Angular Material2 md-checkbox border color

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I am using Angular Material **2** and I am trying to apply css on md-checkbox. So far I managed to change background color, but there is no documentation on how to apply on border color.

My code for height-width:

```
:host /deep/ .mat-checkbox-inner-container{
     height:15px;
     width:15px; 
}
```

code for background color on check:

```
 :host /deep/  .mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: #72addc;
}
```

but still cannot apply on border color.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: just use  like `border:1px solid black`

Comment: @SankarRaj your suggestion creates a new border right next to the current. Does not apply on the check-box initial border. Thank you for your answer by the way

Comment: So that you should use `outline` instead of `border`

Comment: @SankarRaj both of your suggestions have the same output. Please have a look: http://imgur.com/a/pLpMC

Comment: Solution: `:host /deep/ .mat-checkbox-frame {
    border-color: white
}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Angular `5+` version

```
/deep/ .mat-checkbox-frame { 
    border-color: grey 
}
```

You can learn more about styling components here https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Comment: So many different solutions out there and this is the only one that worked for me. Cheers

Answer (score 7):

For Angular 8

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-frame {
  border-color: white
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to add that "/deep/" is deprecated Now. [from version 8]
use "::ng-deep" instead of  "/deep/"

First time I removed ":host"  but after removing it did not work properly.
So I added it again.

**CSS Using for Border Color:**

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-frame { 
    border-color: white 
}
```

**CSS Using for Background color change:**

```
:host ::ng-deep  .mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: #01ADE4;
}
```